# Game of pong ball is getting stuck at line in unity 3d 2020

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game called pong as we all no from this tutorial  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHSanceczXY however my ball is getting stuck in the line that separates the two players I am using unity 2020 version 1.1.11f1 Personal DX 11

[image]

My Ball script is as follows

```
public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
 {
  public float speed;
  public Rigidbody2D rb;
  // Start is called before the first frame update
  void Start()
  {
      Launch();
  }


  private void Launch()
  {
    float x = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
    float y = Random.Range(0, 2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
  }
}
```

However speed of the ball is set to 5 as suggested in the tutorial

[image]

And the line object is setup as such

[image]

However i cannot figure out why my ball is getting stuck at the line. Do you guys be able to help thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if the "Line" has a rigidbody/collider on it? this could be causing the collision system to get the ball stuck in it or on it.

just click on the line -> scroll down in the inspector -> check for a rigidbody or collider -> remove it if it is there.

//edit

i now see that you do have a box collider, if you need to check for collisions, set it to isTrigger else just remove it. that will probably fix the issue

Comment: thanks for the help some people can be so snobby

Comment: hahah, yeah i know. I hope it works! if it doesnt get back to me and ill do my best to get the right answer!